# How to implement reset functionality for @Singleton ejb

Tags: java, ejb

I have used `@Singleton` ejb in my application and it is working fine but i want a reset functionality to the ejb singleton and i am not getting how to implement it

```
@Singleton
@Stateless
public class TestImpl implements TestLocal{

private Datasource source;

@Override
public Datasource getDataSource(){
     return source;
}

//I want reset method which will rest my datasource object

}
```

Comment: I don't think a datasource should be exposed outside the class as it most likely is managed by the container. Find a good tutorial and start from there.

Comment: yes you are right,but this is just example if i want reset other members of class?

Comment: Create a method that change the member variables to whatever you like. But since this is a stateless bean, it shouldn't really have a state... Go find the tutorial :-)